# How to Write a Series of Questions

Tags: questions

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the appropriate article to assist me. I'm writing clinical paper work and I need to know how to write a series of question. Here's my series of questions, how would I write this whole section? Do I need to add semicolons or question marks or get rid of any commas or colons?

This is not a numbered list. We simply have to include it in a journal that we turn in to our nursing instructor. I just need to know how to write out a series of questions in a paper. I didn’t think it’d be appropriate to write a bulleted list, but I’m not sure of the grammar rules for asking multiple questions in a paragraph. She asked us what type of questions would we ask our when we assessed them. I took the snippet below from my paper:

> Some questions I would have asked my patient include: “Have you noticed any joint stiffness”, “What are your typical everyday activities and how have they been impacted”, “How would you describe the pain you’re having and what makes it worse”.

Comment: Is this a numbered list? ... I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for writing advice.  Answers to this question as posed will tend to be subjective and primarily opinion based

Comment: In any case, you'd want to put a question mark inside the quotes for each question.

Answer (score 0):

I would indent the questions and list them separately with a bullet before each.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like bullets in the context, you could ask each question separately and also leave out the quotations after the semi-colon.

> Some questions I would have asked my patient include: Have you noticed
>   any joint stiffness? What are your typical everyday activities and how
>   have they been impacted? How would you describe the pain you’re having
>   and what makes it worse?